# view doesn't match storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, view, storyboard

I don't have a single clue about this :

I build a simple view in a storyboard (i have buttons, a table view, labels... nothing fancy), and it simply does not match what i get on my device.

For example, the background color of my buttons, or the text they contain. I have no idea why, but since I don't know when (sadly), the storyboard is stuck to a state and no matter what I change, nothing changes when i run it.

Can add views, can't modify anything.

I'm using the wCompact hRegular "style", because it looks like an iPhone( and i'm only building for iPhone), but I also don't understand what that really does and it might be related. When i change this "style", all the views are blank and my outlets are greyed out.

Any help leading in the right direction is most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

OK, first off...

The `wCompact hRegular` thing is called size classes. And yes, this is that cause of the problem.

You only need to change these when making an app for multiple devices (iPhone, iPad, etc).

If you're making it for iPhone only then don't touch them. Leave them on `wAny hAny`.

What it does is set certain interfaces/layout for only creating devices.

Unfortunately you have already changed this so the best (easiest) solution might be to delete it all and start again (in the Storyboard) and make sure you set it to `wAny hAny`.

You can set everything straight if you know what is wrong in the first place. But as you said that you don't know what's wrong thats why I suggest deleting everything.

You can read more about Size Classes in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html).

Comment: You are right. But "wCompact hRegular" should work if he is running on iPhone. What do you think?

Comment: @Anil the OP has almost certainly put some UI in with one size class then changed it and updated. Then changed again, etc... Once it get's to this stage you need to know what you're doing.

Comment: @Anil of course, I'm assuming that the AutoLayout stuff isn't the issue because he didn't mention layout more the properties of the buttons themselves (like images, colours, etc...)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I created my very first CV in wCompact/hRegular, and i didn't change it back and forth. I also created views and VC's and all my good jazz went just fine until now. I'm working in a team so _maybe_ someone did a commit with Any/Any without me noticing and then i commited back against it, or something like that... Anyway, I guess i'll just recreate my whole storyboard...

Comment: @Zil in which simulator you are running?

Comment: I'm running on an iPhone 4S device, not simulator.

Comment: @Fogmeister Layouts were fine, now its just "everything" that is not occuring. When the problem was not there, my layouts were reacting normally, and now whatever i do (move stuff, change properties, create view), my result won't change. As if I was loading another storyboard (which i'm not...).

But in code i can call my outlet and change it programatically, if i want to (which i don't :D°

Comment: @Zil it definitely sounds like you're working on the wrong size class. It's hard/impossible to tell what exactly is happening without being able to see it though.

Comment: Also, if that is useful : all my items (buttons, etc.) are `wC|hR` Installed ; i could just Install them for `wAny|hAny` and resize them to my will and it would work again? That would save me a lot of time rather than just CtrlA + Deleting everything !

Comment: @Zil C|R will override Any|Any. So if you change to Any|Any and update the buttons then the "status" they have in C|R will not change and will take precedence. It's worth a try though. Also, does the app have landscape and portrait? If so, which is not working? Or both?

Comment: The app is only iphone, only portrait, this is why i wanted ot owkr in C|R. I've been messing with the Install checkboxes in the different class sizes, but to no avail. I can't get to change what in my view :( I guess i'll have to redraw everything

Comment: Whatever happens, if I change a button title (for example) in EVERY class size, I should see it changed on the device, right?
Even that does not work :≤

Comment: @Zil like I said. Without actually being able to see it it's pretty much impossible to help. I can only take guesses at what it sounds like.

Comment: Fair enough :( 'm not allowed to share any files though. I guess we're done here ! I'll vote you up. Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: @Zil sorry I can't help any further. The only thing I can suggest is to make sure the subclass is set correctly in the storyboard. Also, go through and triple check everything bit by bit. Are you certain that the correct storyboard is being loaded etc...

Comment: I uninstalled the app and reinstalled it, it loads fine now. No change was done whatsoever, I simply had to reinstall and now he takes the changes into account again. (And I don't need to reinstall everytime).
I guess it's just Xcode/Apple messing with me again.